# Adding a Spring dependency into a gradle task

Tags: maven, gradle, groovy

I want to add a special gradle task on my machine as an init script.  The script is in ~/.gradle/init.d.  Let's call it servertest.gradle.  It looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType

allprojects {
    task servertest {
        doLast {
            MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json")
        }
    }
}
```

I can run the task, but it says this:

```
> startup failed:
  initialization script '/home/user1/.gradle/init.d/servertest.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class org.springframework.http.MediaType
   @ line 1, column 1.
     import org.springframework.http.MediaType
     ^

  1 error
```

Of course, what I really need to do is more complicated than this, but this is a simplified example of using a Spring Library in a Gradle Task.

How do I import the spring libraries into a task?

Comment: Was it the complete gradle file? or partial? added dependencies?

Comment: This is the complete file.  It is an init gradle script.  See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html for more details.

Comment: Please check the solution and see if that resolves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, dependency missing.

The `MediaType` class is in `spring-web` library.

Here is how the `gradle` file with dependency should look like:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
initscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
       classpath group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE'
    }
}

allprojects {
    task servertest {
        doLast {
            MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that did it.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @User1, glad that it helped.